# Cardinality of $\{x\in \Bbb R:\ln(x)∈ \Bbb Q\}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> Check whether $$A=\{x\in \Bbb R:\ln(x)∈ \Bbb Q\}$$ 
>    is countable or not

I need to prove this is countable or not so from what I see that for every element in set $\Bbb R$ there will always be $1$ answer for $\ln(x)$ which will make a $1$ on $1$ situation which is countable. Is this a right way to solve this question? If it was is there any better way to look into it ?

Answer (score 2):

$A=\{e^{q}:q \in \mathbb Q\}$ so $A$ is countable.

Answer (score 1):

Just rephrased a bit:

$\mathbb{Q}$ is countable, i.e.

$\mathbb{Q} =${$y_i| i \in \mathbb{N}$ }.

Consider the function

$f: \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^+_{\star}}$

$f(y_i): e^{y_i} = :x_i$,  $i=1,2,3,...$.

$B:=$ {$x_i| i \in \mathbb{N}$ } is countable, and

$B \subset A$;

To show equality:

Let $a \in A$:

Then $\log a \in \mathbb{Q}$, i.e there is a $k \in \mathbb{N}$, s.t. $\log a =y_k$, then $e^{\log a}= a =e^{y_k} =x_k \in B$, and we are done.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have the right idea. No two different real numbers have the same logarithm, so there's no way your set could be larger than $\mathbb Q$. It can be written as $\{\exp(q) : q \in \mathbb Q\}$. Since $\mathbb Q$ is countable, this set is also countable.

Comment: how did we get $e^q:q∈Q$? is there a name to this so i can look it up and understand it?

Comment: Are you asking about [set-builder notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation#More_complex_expressions_on_the_left_side_of_the_notation) or the relationship between the [natural logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm) and the [exponential function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function)?

Comment: Not sure if that's what you call it but basically i mean how did you figure out that notation and how did it prove that it makes the set countable?

Comment: I'm pretty sure reviewing those three topics will help you understand this problem.